# Spin-orbit and internal magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, spin-orbit

I'm currently studying the fine structure of the hydrogen atom but there is something about spin-orbit interaction that I can't understand.
The spin-orbit interaction adds a new term to the Hamiltonian
$$-\boldsymbol{\mu}\cdot\boldsymbol{B}$$
Where $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ is the magnetic dipole moment due to spin and $\boldsymbol{B}$ is the magnetic field that interacts with the dipole. Some books give a semiclassical picture considering the "frame of reference" of the electron, moving in a **centripetal motion** around the nucleus. In this frame the proton is "revolving" around the electron and thus generating a magnetic field. Here comes the problem:
at this point they use the relation:
$$\boldsymbol{B}=-\frac{\boldsymbol{v}\times\boldsymbol{E}}{c^2}$$
Where $\boldsymbol{E}$ is the electric field in the proton rest frame. This formula can be derived as first order (in $\frac{v}{c}$) approximation of the field generated by a charge in uniform motion, that can be in turn derived by Lorentz transformations or via classical electrodynamics. In this case, though, there is non-zero acceleration (centripetal motion) so Lorentz transformation shouldn't be used and the field turns out to be quite complicated. At the end of the story, the result is not correct but it misses a $\frac{1}{2}$ factor. I read that this factor naturally appears in Dirac's relativistic theory but I'm not interested in that here. I found online that there is also a classical explanation, called *Thomas precession*, but I still cannot figure out why they don't consider the field generated by a charge in **arbitrary** motion?
Just for clarity, I mean the one considering both the velocity and the acceleration fields.

Comment: The Lorentz transformation can still be used for an accelerating frame, but it will be a time dependent transformation.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I meant that you have to apply Lorentz transformation at each instant.

Comment: If you add everything, it is just harder to calculate. One option is to remain in the frame of the nucleus and see how a magnetic dipole transforms under motion, this can be done but it is still full of technical nuances.